# Error when install npm in localhost, wamp

Tags: php, laravel, windows, npm-install

I'm trying to install npm install on my WAMP server with localhost now many times.

I have update PHP, npm and composer but with no success.

I don't know what to do, I have tried many different options.
And I really need node_modules to my Laravel project.

This is the I get:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "C:\Python27\python.exe" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.13.1' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.13.1"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\node-sass\build
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 Found installation at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Found Microsoft.VisualStudio.VC.MSBuild.Base
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017   - Using this installation with Windows 10 SDK
npm ERR! gyp verb find vs2017 using installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\node-sass\build\config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:28224) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\node-sass\config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "msvs"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\nikla\\.node-gyp\\16.13.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\nikla\\.node-gyp\\16.13.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\nikla\\.node-gyp\\16.13.1\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\node_modules\\node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\node_modules\\node-sass\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp verb command build []
npm ERR! gyp verb build type Release
npm ERR! gyp verb architecture x64
npm ERR! gyp verb node dev dir C:\Users\nikla\.node-gyp\16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp verb found first Solution file build/binding.sln
npm ERR! gyp verb using MSBuild: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\wamp\\www\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxxxxx\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
npm ERR! gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 7
```

Hope someone can help me.

npm v9.8.1

node v16.13.1

node-gyp v v3.8.0

Comment: This requires reading the error message, not just throwing re-installs on it wildly, but the one that was requested: Have you tried to update node-gyp? And if not have you filed an issue?